# Vectors and magnitude

Tags: vectors

The question states: Under what conditions is |**u**+**v**|= |**u**|+|**v**|? Include a diagram in your explanation. I know the parameters for |**u**+**v**| is less than or equal to of |**u**|+|**v**|. I just need a clarification of when they are both equal.

Comment: Have you heard of the parallelogram construction? It is essentially about when the sum of lengths of two sides is equal to its diagonal....now think about it

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture and consider a few different angles between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @A.Lee A picture can speak volumes, however the provided answer takes the algebra approach which should be enrichment for the material. Soon you will encounter Cauchy Schwartz anyway